# WinSCP: Is it possible to prevent folder of certain name from being uploaded?

Tags: npm, ftp, node-modules, file-transfer, winscp

I often use NPM and the node_modules folder contains thousands upon thousands of sub directories. Even though they are small, remote file transfers of this many files or directories takes hours to write so many files.

Many times I am deploying a whole directory and don't realize that there is a node_modules that I have not manually deleted somewhere deep in the tree structure.

Is it possible to ignore folders of a certain name or alert me if uploading a certain folder?

In git I can just ignore it with **/node_modules, but I don't know of an equivalent for FTP transfers.

Comment: In WinSCP GUI? Or do you have some script for the upload?

Comment: Preferably  GUI or settings

Comment: OK, then your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please move it to [su] (delete here, re-post there). .